# How to Stop ActiveMQ for certain time and again start it?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I want a java code to stop ActiveMQ for 5mins when there are 1000 messages in my Input Topic. And then again start it after 5mins .

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can enable jmx and use the JMX api to connect to activemq.  Get hold of the borker and invoke the stop operation on it.  You can do the same thing for specific queues as well.

Do this using jconsole first. If it works figure out how to do the same thing using the JMX api.

http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html

Comment: Thanks !
But i will not be able to read my 1000 messages after this. Right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run listener in Thread, pause thread when you get 1000 messages, than you can resume thread after timeout.